# Create Report in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC using C# in Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: c#, report, rdlc, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-7.0

In the past (long away) I used Crystal Report to make reports, at this moment I am using Visual Studio 2022. I am trying to make reports for ASP.NET Core 7 MVC, I found and install Microsoft RDLC Report Designer from Marketplace and just give me the chance to create a Report Project Server and YES I can create report in this project but I want to show this reports in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC.

I create a solution with multi projects with separate logic (model + MVC + library + report) and I can't add the report the reference to the ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project.

The report ASP.NET Project is based on the .NET Framework and I am working with .NET 7.

Anybody have a really experience making reports in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC / Visual Studio 2022 using the Microsoft RDLC Report Designer or other? At this point, I can change the library or plugin or Nuget package to make it work.

My solution with separate logic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal Runtime is not compatible with .NET Core -- only with .NET.
Your best option is to delegate the Crystal Reports functionality to your own .NET implementation or to a 3rd-party Crystal Reports viewer that provides a command line API.